# How do I pass an array to another class to find the minimum value?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing, min

I am trying to find the minimum value in an array by way of creating a new Java class. I am having trouble passing in the array and using it to find the minimum value of an array.

I have a total of two separate arrays that I am trying to find the value of.

Here is the first class I created:

```
import java.util.*;

public class mooseWeight
{
    public int main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] length1;
        int[] length2;

        length1 = new int[20];
        length2 = new int[50];

        //Length 1
        System.out.println("Array 1:");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i<length1.length; i++)
        {
            length1[i] = rnd.nextInt(400) + 250;
            System.out.println(length1[i]);
            return length1[i];
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

        //Length2
        System.out.println("Array 2:");
        Random rnd2 = new Random();
        for(int j = 0; j < length2.length; j++)
        {
            length2[j] = rnd2.nextInt(400) + 250;
            System.out.println(length2[j]);
            return length2[j];
        }
    }
}
```

This is currently set up to find the minimum value of length1[] (aka the first array).

This is the class I am trying to pass the arrays into:

```
public class minWeight
{
    public static int getArrayMin(int[] arr)
    {
        mooseWeight array1[] = new mooseWeight[];


        int minValue = array1[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
        {
            if (array1[i] < minValue) 
            {
                minValue = array1[i];
            }

            //return minValue;
        }
        return minValue;
        System.out.println(minValue);
    }
}
```

My current error:

```
1 error found:
File: D:\2016-2017\Fall2016\201_CSCE_Programming\Lab 7\minWeight.java  [line: 5]
Error: array dimension missing
```

Comment: mooseWeight array1[] = new mooseWeight[];
You have to give a size to the array

Comment: `mooseWeight array1[] = new mooseWeight[];` is creating an array of `mooseWeight` objects. You're creating it, then trying to get values from it. If you're storing `int` in the array, you need to create an array of ints. As it is, you are passing in `arr`, so remove all references to `array1` and replace them with `arr`, then loose that `mooseWeight` line, it's not actually doing anything.

Comment: @Brunaldo I have 2 arrays that I am trying to pass through. My first array is length 20. do I put '20' in the brackets '[]'?

Comment: Code quality comment: it's best to follow Java naming conventions: classes use CamelCase with an initial capital letter, so that people can easily tell them apart from variables/methods, which use camelCase with an initial lowercase letter. As such, calling your classes `MooseWeight` and `minWeight` brings them in line with what the professional Java world expects to see. And then on a practical note: your `MooseWeight` is your entry point class. Don't make instances of that in other classes (executing your program already does that). It's the one class you almost always want to leave alone.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the classes use PascalCase and the variables and methods use camelCase see the MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Blip so, literally what I said, then. The code shown does not follow these conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mooseWeight` class contains your main, so when you're creating `array1`, you're trying to create an array containing your actual program.

`mooseWeight array1[] = new mooseWeight[];` is creating an array of mooseWeight objects.

As you don't define a size, this will fail, but even if it didn't, it wouldn't work.

I assume that you meant to create an array of `int`, then loop over it.

If you created an array of `int`, then tried to loop over it without adding anything, the loop won't do anything as there's nothing to iterate over.

In your method, you pass in an array of `int` called `arr`, so you need to use that to loop over.

If you're trying to pass 2 arrays into the method, creating an array as part of your method still won't work.

You need to modify your method declaration to accept a second array.

Assuming you want to find the smallest value from both of these arrays, I've modified my code snippet to do just that.
If you need to process your second array differently, modify the loop which deals with `secondArr`.

As mentioned in comments, your `mooseWeight` class should be named `MooseWeight` to keep with correct Java naming conventions.

A class name is in PascalCase, with instances in camelCase.

To call the method, use the following snippet.

```
int[] ar1 = new int[20];
int[] ar2 = new int[50];
//Populate your arrays with values....

int minValue = MinWeight.getArrayMin(ar1, ar2);
```

Class:

```
 public class MinWeight {
      public static int getArrayMin(int[] arr, int[] secondArr) {

        int minValue = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < minValue) 
            {
                minValue = arr[i];
            }
         }

        for (int i = 0; i < secondArr.length; i++) {
            if (secondArr[i] < minValue) 
            {
                minValue = secondArr[i];
            }
         }          
        System.out.println(minValue);
        return minValue;
      }
    }
```

As a final concern, in your code, you return `minValue` before you try to print the result, so the print instruction is always unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The error in minWeight not fom the array parameter, it is from this line:

```
mooseWeight array1[] = new mooseWeight[];
```

You cannot allocate an array of unknown dimension in java.
Also, your attempt to do so makes no sense.
Just delete the line above from your java method and change the name of the parameter to array1.

Get an IDE like netbeans or eclipse.

Comment: I suspect that this might be part of a college assignment, which could prevent the use of an IDE. When I was doing my degree, we had to work in a plan text editor for all Java assignments. Deeply frustrating, but I can sort of understand why educational establishments do it. It doesn't help to prepare any graduates for the real world though. Switching to NetBeans was absolute bliss after that!